# Electrical Power production response to complete transition to electric vehicles

Tags: electricity

Just wondering if current world wide power grid capacity could handle a complete transition to electrical vehicles. If every existing vehicle was electric would the existing power production handle it on a global level?

Comment: Or would we end up burning fuel to charge the batteries?

Comment: I suggest you do some research into this and come back when you have a valid EE question for this site.

Comment: You are right, it very generic but I think it needs electrical engineering expertise and is valid.

Comment: Have a 2,500 watt solar panel setup at each  home, used to charge a redundant battery during the day. Then at night, you swap out battery for battery. Little or no grid needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Burning fuel to charge batteries as the absolute worst case has somewhere between similar, and slightly better efficiency than burning fuel in a car, as the motor can always be run at optimal efficiency.

For trains, this has been done for ages -- quite a lot of diesel engines are really "serial hybrid" setups where a diesel generator feeds an electric engine, as this is more efficient. This is also being done for some cars targeted at customers that require individual mobility with long range.

This is the worst case, however. Since electric cars do not require grid power while they are running, but rather when they are idle, it is possible to schedule the charging cycles during off-peak times. Electricity companies are already introducing remotely managed charging ports that are turned on only for a few hours at night, and house battery solutions that can be charged from a rooftop solar panel, all of which reduce the strain on the grid that is introduced by electric cars.

Total demand however still increases. Right now, excess energy produced at night is stored by pumping water uphill, when we charge cars instead, this energy will be missing throughout the day, when consumption exceeds production.

There are also be non-technical effects on grid load, such as telecommuting, online shopping, automation in manufacturing (there are several factories that usually run in the dark as there are no humans inside), ... All of these effects combined shape how and if the grid changes to accommodate demand.

I'd expect that in the next ten years, demand for individual mobility will go down quite a bit, while logistics demand will rise even further, so many electric cars will be commercial, and they will be charged over night in industrial areas.

Comment: The question was if the grid could handle **complete transition**.

Comment: Instantaneous? No. Over several years as cars get replaced? Of course. The grid is not a static thing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Enerdata](https://yearbook.enerdata.net/electricity/electricity-domestic-consumption-data.html) the yearly electricity power consumption in the world is around 220TWh and growing by 2 to 3% each year , 4.4 to 6.6TW more each year.

The [yearly energy consumption](https://www.eia.gov/outlooks/ieo/pdf/transportation.pdf) of the transportation sector is around  150000TBtu ~= 44TWh most of it from fossil fuel.

So even taking into account a 80% battery efficiency it's hard to believe that the power generation industry will not handle the transition to electric vehicles that could last more than 10 years due to other factors like the price of the electric vehicles.

Answer (score -2):

No.

The highest voltage levels in the grid are sized just so the feeds of a node could supply current replacing an outage of one single "local" power station at that node when they are **combined**.

Why is it designed this way? Because it is uneconomical to ship current through the grid. Electrical power has to be generated **locally**. As soon you are a few hundred kilometres away, moving the fuel instead is much more economical. Build railways and pipelines instead of electrical poles.

The only exception from that rule is when your fuel cannot be shipped. Hydroelectric dams for example. Or offshore wind.

---

The electrical grid in Germany, for example, can hardly stand both the generated wind power and power from lignite fired power stations at the same time. And Germany has one of the best developed electrical grids worldwide. As soon the wind power goes up, the coal firing has to be shut down. And vice versa.

To account for that, two HVDC long-range lines from the north to the south are currently planned, so the offshore wind power stations in the north do not overload the Northern and central grid any more and the wind-electric power could be distributed to Southern Germany and Czech.

Comment: There have been suggestions for freeway floodlight stations to support wireless WPT charging on rest stops,when the lights are not in use but that’s 10yrs away but operational with 11kW WPT chargers now 22kW in future per vehicle

Comment: The electric energy transport is one of the less expensive. The efficiency is up to 85%. However, storing the electric energy is costly and inefficient so that's why every country, not only Germany does that. The coal firing is shut down when there is a cheaper energy source available and started again when there is no other source available. Only costs reasons , nothing to do with the electrical grid power rating.

Comment: Yeah, sure. And that's why they plan HVDC lines. They are not needed.